# Is there a word or expression for improving software

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a text and I have to say what skills I developed during my internship. What do you call improving software? Software improvement? I feel like there would be a better word or expression for this.

**EDIT**: By improving, I mean that I added features to the software that were requested by the company.

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific on how you improved the software and whether it was part of development or if you made suggestions that resulted in the existing software being "better" (faster, more efficient, more features?)

Comment: @Kristina Lopez I added more features to it that were requested by the company. It's kinda more efficient but in term of ms so it's not really relevant.

Comment: One particular word often associated with "enhancing" software is ***optimization***. But probably the most common advice regarding [software] optimization is ***Don't do it!*** (you'll probably introduce new bugs that outweigh any potential advantages, and it's usually unnecessary because the hardware keeps getting more powerful anyway). Programmers always want to be allowed to spend time optimizing / "perfecting" their cherished *magnum opus*; managers always want them to get to work on *new* projects that will actually earn more money for the company.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But adding features isn't really optimization right? I think improvement is better in my situation.

Comment: @loli: If that distinction is important in the context of the question you need to *edit the question* to include it. Comments on ELU are potentially "ephemeral", and may be deleted by mods at any time. Besides which, potential answerers quite reasonably expect that all relevant factors should be in the actual question, not buried somewhere in comments.

Comment: While all the comments are certainly true, the bottom line, IMO, is that a future employer would like to know *how* you improved the software and what tools/apps/language/skills you used to accomplish that.

Comment: I'd use **enhancing** or **iterating**. **Refactoring** doesn't entail improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to avoid overstating your contributions because you feel terms like "upgrade" may imply you completely overhauled the software, you might say that you **made enhancements to** or **extended** the software.

Comment: Remove the "or refactor" part, as it is unrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps "refactoring" the code would fit your need?

> [refactoring](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/refactoring) - Improving a computer program by reorganising its internal structure without altering its external behaviour.

Or you "extended" the program.  The definition fitting this usage is...

> [extend](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extend) - to increase the scope, meaning, or application of

Comment: While it is an improvement, it is not really the one specified in my edit.

Comment: That's true.  Perhaps saying you "extended" the code would work.

Comment: Extended sounds good, but I prefer improved. You should still add it in your answer for future readers

Comment: Given that OP (commendably, imho) specifically edited the question to indicate that he's talking about ***additional features***, ten minutes before your answer, I feel I have to downvote ***refactoring***.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making it better by adding onto it **upgrade** would be an apt description

> **[Upgrade](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/upgrade)**-
>   2. an increase or improvement
>   3. a new version, improved model, etc.
>   4.an increase or improvement in one's service, accommodations, privileges, or the like
>   5. something, as a piece of equipment, that serves to improve or enhance
>
> **[Upgrade](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/upgrade)**- Raise (something) to a higher standard, in particular improve (equipment or machinery) by adding or replacing components

To a lesser extent **[ameliorate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ameliorate)**- to make or become better, more bearable, or more satisfactory; improve

Comment: How would you call such skill? Software Upgradement?

Comment: Either "upgraded software" or simply "software upgrade" would refer to the software. Upgradeability would be the software's capacity to be upgraded. As for experience/ability to upgrade you could say "I have the capacity to upgrade software".

Comment: An upgrade to software is usually a much more involved endeavor that would include bug fixes and enhancements with the requisite release notes so you really couldn't say you single-handedly upgraded software.  It's more of a project that involves a team.

Comment: I used ameliorate so that's why I marked this as chosen answer, but in my language, it basically means improve.

Comment: In theory "ameliorate" has the right meaning here, but it is often incorrectly used instead of "alleviate," with the meaning of "making a very bad situation slightly better, but not fixing the fundamental cause of the problem." That is probably *not* the meaning you want to give to a reader who doesn't use "ameliorate" correctly. See http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ameliorate. "Enhance" is often used for improvements to software, but the cynical meaning of "software enhancements" is just "changes", and not necessarily "improvements".

Comment: @loli: Native speakers tend to use the noun form ***a** software upgrade* to mean *a **new release** of the software [which performs better/has more features than earlier versions]*. But the activity itself (actually *coding* the upgrade) is more likely to be called ***enhancement***, for which the more common verb form is, say, *I worked on **enhancing** existing software, rather than writing new applications*. I do not think ***ameliorate*** has any particular relevance to software "improvements" - it's more about reducing (emotional) grief than increasing performance in an IT context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I really like enhancement, it sounds better. And thanks alephzero for specification about possible misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single word, but I'd probably use pretty much the same phrasing you used in your question: "I added features" or "I added functionality".

To me, the word "extended" suggests that you created extensions—separate pieces of software which work with the existing software to extend its functionality—rather than modifying the software to add functionality. But maybe this misunderstanding is unlikely.

I think all the other suggestions I've seen (enhanced, improved, upgraded, ameliorated) are too vague, because they could easily refer to other types of improvement besides adding new features.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're answering the wrong question.  All previous answers have addressed you finding a word to describe the task you were doing.  But this isn't what you say you're being asked for.

If they're wanting to know what new skills you learnt, they don't care whether you refactored code or wrote new features or whatever.  That isn't a skill, that's a task.  A skill is something like "how to program in C", or "how to code for test".  Your tasks are how you learnt those skills.

Remember that you're writing this for someone else to read.  Check again what you're being asked to give them.  And after you've written it, pretend that you're them and read it as if it was something that had just been handed to you, using the criteria that you've been given.  Then go back and rework the bits that don't fit what someone in that position would be looking for.